# How to debug Firefox's XUL startup (on Windows)

Tags: debugging, firefox, xul, xulrunner, firefox-developer-tools

I have a problem that causes Firefox to behave strangely during startup. 

(Specifically, it displays the "*Firefox seems slow... to... start*" message, even though I didn't install any new extensions or anything like that.)

The function that displays that message is `_showSlowStartupNotification` in `browser/components/nsBrowserGlue.js` which is called from `_trackSlowStartup` which in turn is called by `_onFirstWindowLoaded`.

I want to debug that. How can I do that?

I can debug the Firefox binaries easily with WinDbg and Mozilla's symbol server. But that's not what I want. I want to debug the XUL, not the C++.

I can debug the XUL if I enable the [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox), but only after the startup. Even if I set `devtools.debugger.prompt-connection` to false and run `firefox.exe -jsdebugger` to immediately open the Browser Toolbox, I get access to it only after the startup code has already been executed. Setting a breakpoint on the interesting function doesn't help as they are not persistent; restarting Firefox doesn't cause the internal XUL debugger to break on them.

So, any suggestions? Is there a way to debug Firefox's XUL from the early start?